# Azure AD authorization for API to API not working

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory

So, my setup in AAD is:
1. I created an app 'api-source'.
2. Then I created an app 'api-caller' and then created a key for the 'api-caller'
3. Note - I did not added 'api-source' in required permissions of 'api-caller'.
4. I used adal-node to get the token for 'api-source' as a resource for 'api-caller' as client id. I was able to use the 'api-caller' with the token I got although, did not added any required permissions.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you show how you are doing authentication and authorization?

Comment: Yeah, more details who help better understand the issue. However, generally speaking ,you do need to add api-source in the required permissions of the api-caller.